# Prevent WordPress automatically processing certain URL queries

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, query

I'm coding a custom plugin for a client and I want to use certain `$_GET` variables in the URL in my custom pages, such as `?s=$1`, `?p=$1` and `?paged=$1`. With some of these variables, such as `?paged=$1`, it redirects me to another URL: `[PAGE_URL]/page/$1`.

Are there any filter or action hooks that I can use to remove these functionalities for particular pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find alternatives, as noted on the codex article of ["Reserved Terms" in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) (emphasis mine):

> There is a complete set of reserved keywords, or terms, in WordPress
>   that should not be used in certain circumstances as they may conflict
>   with core functionality. **You should avoid using any of these terms
>   when**:
>
> - **Passing a term through a $_GET or $_POST array**
> - Registering a taxonomy or post type slug
> - Handling query variables

You could use `?search=` in place of `?s=` and `?pg=` in place of `?page=` for example.

Or, depending on what exactly you're doing, you could create a custom rewrite rule with [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) and then you could name the underlying query vars whatever you wanted.